# Gem countries select helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, country

I am trying to use the gem `countries` from `hexorx`.  I really don't know how to bring that in the select helper. I tried to use the helper `country_select` like this

```
<%= f.country_select :country, :required => true %>
```

The GitHub location of gem is https://github.com/hexorx/countries.

Answer (score 1):

The interface for this helper is defined as:

```
country_select(object, method, priority_countries = nil, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

I found this by going to the link you supplied, navigating through the source code to [`/lib/countries/select_helper.rb`](https://github.com/hexorx/countries/blob/master/lib/countries/select_helper.rb)

Assuming this is in a `form_for` operating on an object instance, perhaps `@user` then an instance of User is what gets passed for the first parameter, `object`.  The second argument, `method` is the attribute of the object that should receive the selected value, so in this example, your User model will need to have an attribute called `country`.

So the problem is likely that the third argument expects a list of `priority_countries`, but it's getting `:required => true`.  If you pass `nil`, then pass your options, it should work, like this:

```
<%= f.country_select :country, nil, :required => true %>
```

For future posts, when something doesn't work, you should provide the complete error message or symptoms that you saw.  [Please refer to the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)